# Can DAB both step up and step down the output voltage in the same design?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, phase-shift, dual-active-bridge

I study this converter through these articles ([1](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9448428) , [2](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidues0c/tidues0c.pdf?ts=1689641661654)).

Attached is the [DAB](https://www.mediafire.com/file/2v6tkwqs4w4p2td/DAB1.asc/file) model for LTSpice.

[image]

[image]

I usually see these converters working in buck mode (input bus with constant voltage PFC, maximum output voltage is achieved through the turn ratio when the phase shift is 0). For example, input 800V, N = 1.6, output 500V, phase shift 0.

I also saw a graph of the ZVS zone, where the voltage transfer value was both less than and greater than 1.

My goal: Vin 400VDC, Output voltage range 200-500VDC, N=1.2 (transformer ratio).

[image]

When creating a phase shift in the LTspice model, I only see the effect of reducing the voltage.

I see this as an [example](https://www.onsemi.com/company/news-media/blog/industrial-cloud-power/25kw-sic-fast-ev-charger-development-structure-specs). That the DAB output is both higher and lower than the input.

[image]

Question: can DAB of the same design both increase and decrease the output voltage? If so, how is this achieved if we only adjust the phase shift from 0 to a certain value? (about the flow of energy in one direction).

Comment: Schematic please.

Comment: She was on the link in the topic. - https://www.mediafire.com/file/2v6tkwqs4w4p2td/DAB1.asc/file

Comment: I don't use LTspice. I mean post a schematic into your question.

Comment: Ok,  Update ....

Comment: Why have you got 10 nF in parallel with each MOSFET? Please show a picture of the timing of the left side and what gets altered when you modify the duty cycle.

Comment: It's a snubber. Duty cycle 50% - fixed.

Comment: On the right bridge, I change the on / off time and thereby regulate the output voltage (resistor on the load). I don't understand how DAB can work in Boost mode when the voltage gain is greater than 1. Through the phase shift, I only see the buck mode. https://i.imgur.com/TpGnLQx.png

Comment: And I see that most DAB work with voltage gain <= 1. I gave one example of a converter where the voltage gain can be either less than or greater than 1 (vin 800VDC, vout 200-1000VDC), as they achieve this range of output voltages with a transformation ratio of 1.2 through a phase shift?

Comment: Have you tried to get the simplified version working in LTspice yet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UylKt.png <-- I don't think this simpler version or the transformer version are going to produce a boost output with phase shifted PWM. I might be wrong of course. I've only ever built step-up single H-bridge transformer coupled output using phase shifted PWM.

Comment: No, I'm just learning LTspice. I see a Buck/Boost converter here, as you mentioned about a year ago in my previous question about this converter. Most likely it is, since most open DAB models operate in the voltage transfer mode <= 1. And the fact that > ​​1 requires something additional.

Comment: I suspect that it uses a step-up transformer to give an increase in output voltage (say 1:2) then, it can buck that down to as small a value as is required. I hope someone can help you out here because I'm at my limit.

Comment: I'm simultaneously studying various information on these converters. Either way, there will be a way out. As a last resort, use the 800V bus in calculations and achieve the required output voltage range. Thank you so much for your help, I often see you helping people in this community!